# TypeScript Type Checking Not Working for JavaScript Functions Using Declaration Files

Tags: javascript, typescript, declaration

I am currently working on a project where I have a mix of JavaScript and TypeScript files. I'm trying to use TypeScript's type checking capabilities for JavaScript functions by using declaration files, but I'm encountering an issue where TypeScript doesn't seem to enforce type checking as expected.

Here's the simplified folder structure of my project:

```
tscodes/
├── tsconfig.json
├── declaration_file_samples.ts   // JavaScript entry point
├── traceFunction.js              // JavaScript implementation file
└── declaration_file.d.ts        // TypeScript declaration file
```

In `declaration_file.d.ts`, I've declared the type signature for a function called `trace`:

```
declare function trace(arg: string | number | boolean);
```

However, when I import and use the `trace` function in my `declaration_file_samples.ts` JavaScript file, TypeScript doesn't seem to enforce the type checking. Even when I remove options like `string` or `number` from the declaration, I don't receive any type errors.

Here's the content of my declaration_file_samples.ts:

```
const trace = require('./traceFunction');

// Using the trace function
trace("trace with string");
trace(true);
trace(1);
```

Here is the `traceFunction.js` file (JavaScript implementation):

```
function trace(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}

module.exports = trace;
```

I have made sure that the paths and filenames are correct. My TypeScript configuration (tsconfig.json) looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

I do `tsc` and then go to the `dist` folder to `node declaration_file_samples.ts`

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or misunderstanding about how TypeScript type checking works with JavaScript functions and declaration files. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding the [`checkJs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs) option to your `tsconfig.json`.